# Dynamically change color based on brightness of background color

Tags: javascript

I'm using [color.js](https://github.com/PitPik/colorPicker/blob/master/colors.js) to convert and do things with colors. I have a few elements which I want to dynamically change based on the background color. So if the background color is dark, then make the text white. If it's light then make the text black.

That is simple to do:

```
myElem.color = color.RGBLuminance > 0.22 ? 'black' : 'white';
```

But I will also have alpha. How can I test against alpha and the brightness of the background?

#### JSFiddle

```js
var myColor = new Colors();

var div = document.getElementById('div'),
  span = document.getElementById('span'),
  rgbColor = myColor.colors.RND.rgb;

myColor.setColor({
  r: 0,
  g: 0,
  b: 0
}, 'rgb');
/*myColor.setColor({
    r: 100,
    g: 200,
    b: 255
}, 'rgb');*/

div.style.backgroundColor = rgba(rgbColor.r, rgbColor.g, rgbColor.b, 0.3);

span.style.color = myColor.colors.RGBLuminance > 0.22 ? 'black' : 'white';



function rgba(r, g, b, a) {
  return "rgba(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + "," + a + ")";
}
```

```css
#div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <span id="span">hello</span>
</div>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/PitPik/colorPicker/master/colors.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the alpha value for your color with

```
myColor.colors.alpha
```

So you can use a check similar to:

```
span.style.color = myColor.colors.RGBLuminance > 0.22 || myColor.colors.alpha < 0.5 ? 'black' : 'white';
```

You'll likely have to play around with the conditions (or add more cases) to get the behavior you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How would I get them to be combined, not 'or'?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "combined". I'm afraid you'll probably have to determine the right combination to match your criteria on your own.

Answer (score 0):

color.js is quite complex and handles a lot of things in the background. So, it actually also takes care of your problem. color.js works internally with 3 layers: the foreground or the color you just picked, then the background color which is the saved color and then the custom (solid, so no alpha) background color (which color.js can't guess so you have to add it to the options):

```
var myColor = new Colors({
        customBG: '#FFF' // e.g. the background color of your page
    });
```

Then you (almost) correctly set the color like:

```
myColor.setColor({ // 
    r: 0,
    g: 0,
    b: 0
}, 'rgb', 0.3); // but then with the correct alpha
```

...and color.js will provide a variable `colors.rgbaMixBGMixCustom.luminance` that delivers the value you need:

```
div.style.backgroundColor = myColor.toString(); // new method in Color()
span.style.color = myColor.colors.rgbaMixBGMixCustom.luminance  > 0.22 ?
    'black' : 'white';
```

`rgbaMixBGMixCustom` means the set `rgba` color mixed (overlay) with `BG` the saved background color which we can ignore here as it's set to `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` and the custom solid background color `Custom` that we set in the beginning (there is also a method `setCustomBackground()` to reset this later on if needed)

`rgbaMixBGMixCustom` also holds information about the resulting color of all 3 layers.